# Is it possible to change icon when program is minimized?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, notifications

I am working on a chat program and I want the program to change icon when it is recieving data but only if its minimized. And when you pull the program up again it should change the icon back. I tried just changing it in my recieving thread like this:

```
def returnrecv():
    while True:
        recieve = s.recv(1024).decode("utf-8")
        winsound.PlaySound('beep.wav', winsound.SND_FILENAME + winsound.SND_ASYNC)
        recieveBox.config(state=NORMAL)
        timeclock = time.strftime('%H:%M')
        recieveBox.insert(END, "[" + timeclock + "]", 'black', "Other: ", 'blue', recieve + "\n\n")
        recieveBox.config(state=DISABLED)
        recieveBox.see("end")

        root.iconbitmap("gouico2.ico")
```

But how would I program it to only do this when the program is minimized?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `root.state()` to check the state of the window.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

def change_icon():
    print (root.state())
    if root.state() == "iconic":
        print ("I am hidden")
    root.after(1000, change_icon)

root.after(1000,change_icon)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks for this! `root.state() == "iconic"` and `root.state() == "normal"` is really what I needed!